# Creating multiple chart in c#

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
            {

                ShowReports(0);

            }


 private void ShowReports(int ComboID)
    { 
                   Graph.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    Graph.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 2;
                    Graph.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MMM-yyy";
                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Date";
                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Average Score (%) ";

                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;

                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 10;

                    Graph.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "Date :#VALX Avg Score(%) :#VALY";

                    Graph.Titles.Add(dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString());
                    Graph.Titles.Add(SetGraphTitile());

                    Graph.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20);
                    Graph.Titles[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                    Graph.Titles[1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 13);
                    Graph.Titles[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                    Graph.Titles[1].Visible = false;

                    // Graph.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Parse(dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString()), dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString());
                    Graph.Series[0].XValueMember = dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                    Graph.Series[0].YValueMembers = dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                    Graph.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;

                    Graph.Legends.Add("Legend1");
                    Graph.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
                    Graph.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
                    Graph.Legends[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;

                    Graph.DataSource = dv;
                    Graph.DataBind();

                }
                else if (dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[7].ToString() == "Bar")
                {


                    Graph.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                    Graph.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 2;
                    //Graph.Series["Series1"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
                    //Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MMM-yyy";
                    //Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Date";
                    //Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Average Score (%) ";
                    Graph.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "(#VALX,#VALY)";

                    Graph.Titles.Add(dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString());
                    Graph.Titles.Add(SetGraphTitile());

                    Graph.Titles[0].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20);
                    Graph.Titles[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                    Graph.Titles[1].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 13);
                    Graph.Titles[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                    Graph.Titles[1].Visible = false;


                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Learning Domains";
                    Graph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Covered";




                    // Graph.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Parse(dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString()), dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString());
                    Graph.Series[0].XValueMember = dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                    Graph.Series[0].YValueMembers = dtReportDetails.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
                    //  Graph.Series[0].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;


                    Graph.Legends.Add("Legend1");
                    Graph.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
                    Graph.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
                    Graph.Legends[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;

                    Graph.DataSource = dv;
                    Graph.DataBind();

                    Random random = new Random();
                    foreach (var item in Graph.Series[0].Points)
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
                        item.Color = c;

                    }

                    Graph.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "0.2";
                    Graph.Series[0]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
                    Graph.Series[0]["PixelPointDepth"] = "99";
                    Graph.Series[0]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
```

}

This is my code for creating graph,for creating 1 graph i have no problem ,but creating more than one i will get error:A chart element with the name 'Legend1' already exists in the 'LegendCollection'.because i am creating same legends each time.So can you help to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Easy fix would be to check if a legend already exists and if so remove and re-add not very efficient though.

Comment: that belongs to the code review site --- apart of that, Graph.Legends.Add("Legend1"); uses Legend1 all the time as stated by @Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code for create 5 graphs..

```
for(int i=0;i< 6;i++)
{
Chart1.Series.Add("Series1" + t.ToString());
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1" + t.ToString());
Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend1" + t.ToString());

Chart1.Series[t].ChartArea = "ChartArea1" + t.ToString();
Chart1.Series[t].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
Chart1.Series[t].BorderWidth = 2;

Chart1.Series[t].ToolTip = "(#VALX,#VALY)";
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].AxisX.Title = "Learning Domains";
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1" + t.ToString()].AxisY.Title = "Covered";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting around the issue of the legend object name should be as simple as setting it via a string that takes your ComboID parameter into account.

string myLegendTitle = "Legend" + ComboID;
Graph.Legends.Add(myLegendTitle);

In order to create multiple charts - on the assumption you're using Microsoft Chart controls would look something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
{
     ShowReports(0);
}


private void ShowReports(int ComboID)
{ 
     var myNewGraph = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
     myNewGraph .Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
     myNewGraph .Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 2;
     myParentControl.Controls.Add(myNewGraph);
}
```

The key points being to instantiate a new Chart in your ShowReports method, then set all the properties specifically as before BUT on the new graph / chart object. Then ensure you add the control to the appropriate container if it's not already there.

If you know you will have, for example, 5 charts, then another approach is to build them at design time instead, and use a switch approach to set your variable, eg.

```
private void ShowReports(int ComboID)
{ 
     Chart myNewGraph;
     switch (ComboID)
     {
         case 1:
             myNewGraph = Graph1;
             break;
     }
     myNewGraph .Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
     myNewGraph .Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,error solved.Can you help yo create a 5 same graph;But using this i will get only one graph.